# How to install HashLink on Windows?

Tags: installation, hashlink

I'm trying to learn development on Heaps.io, and they recommended to install HashLink VM to get started. (https://heaps.io/documentation/installation.html).

So I'm just following the documentation I found about HashLink and I don't understand the installation step: https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/hashlink/wiki/Building-and-Installing.

I installed on my computer haxe, haxelib, Visual Studio Code. When I open the hl.sln file, it just open it on VSC but nothing is happening. And I don't know how to compile it, VSC doesn't propose me to compile anything.

Expected: hl command working on prompt

Reality: hl not recognized

Answer (score 2):

You just need to download the latest binary version on:

```
https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/hashlink/releases
```

Then unzip and put on some folder on your computer.

Then go to the System Properties -> Environment variables, edit the path variable then add the location of your hashlink location that you saved.